# ¿Como funciona opacity de CSS?

Tags: html, css

¿Por qué funciona cuando el `Padre` tiene `opacity: 1` y el `Hijo-1` tiene `opacity: 0` y NO cuando el `Padre` tiene `opacity: 0` y el Hijo-1  tiene `opacity: 1`?

El código  siguiente:

```css
.Caja {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.Padre {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Hijo-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Padre">
  <div class="Hijo-1 Caja">1</div>
  <div class="Hijo-2 Caja">2</div>
  <div class="Hijo-3 Caja">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no entiendo en realidad que quieres, quizá mas información, trata de usar la herramienta de stack para mostrar el ejemplo.

Comment: A que le llamas no funciona? si al padre le pones opacidad 0, nada de lo que contenga el padre va a ser visible. por lo tanto no deberías ver nada.

Comment: Que es lo que se debería mostrar según tu criterio con el padre en cero y el hijo en 1, para que podamos entender como ayudarte.

Comment: Cuando Padre esta en CERO y el Hijo en UNO, pues debe mostrarse solamente el Hijo, pero no se muestra....

Comment: Ustedes tienen que cambiar los valores: El Padre era 1, ahora vale 0.  El hijo era 0, ahora vale 1.... y lo tienen que EJECUTAR.....

Comment: Ese es el problema si el padre esta en CERO nada de lo que contenga debe mostrarse. por lo tanto no veras ninguno de sus hijos tengan UNO o no

Comment: Pero cuando el Padre es 1 y el Hijo 0, ahí SI se cumple la "cascada" CSS... pero no al revés....   ES DECIR... el Hijo que tiene 0 no se muestra....

Comment: Obiamente porque si el padre es visible (opacity = 1) entonces los hijos que tengan opacity 1 tambien seran visibles, pero si el padre es invisible (opacity 0) no importan la visibilidad de sus hijos ya que son invisibles porque su padre es invisible.

Comment: Entonces en algunos casos NO se cumple la "cascada".  CSS (Cascade Style Sheets)... ese es el FONDO... la FORMA es eso lo del BACKGROUND

Comment: @peruvice, me parece que estas confundiendo el concepto de cascada con el efecto de las distintas propiedades.

Comment: Creo que estas confundiendo **estilos en cascada** con **herencia**, opacity no solo afecta al elemento, sino todo lo anidado en este y los elementos anidados no pueden deshacerse de esta propiedad. No es comportamiento anormal, así lo definieron los desarrolladores.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando aplicas opacidad a un elemento se aplica a dicho elemento y a todos sus elementos hijos, es decir, si ocultas un elemento padre nunca podrás ver al elemento hijo. En cambio, si ocultas al hijo solamente, al estar el padre visible, seguirás viendo al padre aunque el hijo este oculto (pero no verías a sus hijos).

Sería algo similar a si intentas recoger manzanas de un manzano: si hay manzano, podrás recoger manzanas, pero no al revés. Aquí el efecto es el mismo.

Si lo que quieres es quitarle el background al elemento padre, podrías utilizar un color `rgba` como fondo al que le puedes poner la transparencia que tiene dicho color.

Ejemplo usando `rgba` y con una transparencia de 1 en el padre y 1 en el hijo:

```css
.Caja {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.Padre {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}

.Hijo-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Padre">
  <div class="Hijo-1 Caja">1</div>
  <div class="Hijo-2 Caja">2</div>
  <div class="Hijo-3 Caja">3</div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo usando `rgba` y con una transparencia de 0 en el padre y 1 en el hijo:

```css
.Caja {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.Padre {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}

.Hijo-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Padre">
  <div class="Hijo-1 Caja">1</div>
  <div class="Hijo-2 Caja">2</div>
  <div class="Hijo-3 Caja">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad [CSS opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) define:

> la transparéncia de un elemento, esto es, en qué grado se superpone el fondo al elemento.

Es decir, se espera es que se vea el fondo del elemento que contiene a `Padre`. Para lograrlo es necesario que todo lo que contenga `Padre` también sea transparente en igual grado.

En [la documentación en ingles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) podes encontrar que:

> la opacidad se aplica al elemento como un todo, incluido su contenido, aunque el valor no sea heredado por elementos secundarios. Por lo tanto, el elemento y sus elementos secundarios tienen la misma opacidad con respecto al fondo del elemento, incluso si tienen opacidades diferentes entre sí.